# SwiftUI attributed string from HTML crashes the app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to convert `HTML` formatted text into an attributed string, and insert it into a `SwiftUI` view.

Firstly I have a `String` extension that converts the `HTML` string to `NSAttributedString`:

```
extension String {
    func convertHtml() -> NSAttributedString {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }

        if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
            return attributedString
        } else {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have created a `HTMLLabel` view:

```
struct HTMLLabel: UIViewRepresentable {

    let html: String

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.attributedText = html.convertHtml()

        return label
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {}

}
```

Then I insert a test into my SwiftUI view:

```
HTMLLabel(html: "<html><body><b>Hello</b> <i>World</i></body></html>")
```

The code crashes each time on `if let attributedString = try? ...` with `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`. I made a test in an empty storyboard project like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 320, height: 50))
        label.attributedText = "<html><body><b>Hello</b> <i>World</i></body></html>".convertHtml()

        view.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

That code executes without any issues. Why doesn't the code work in a `SwiftUI` context?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use This:-

```
struct HTMLLabel: UIViewRepresentable {

let html: String

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UILabel {
    let label = UILabel()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let attributedText = self.html.convertHtml() {
               label.attributedText = attributedText
            }
    }

    return label
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {}

}
```

NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html is Only Work with Main Thread That's why you are getting crash