# multiline textview inside list / ForEach SWIFTUI with dynamic cell height

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios13, swiftui-list

Need to display html formatted text inside the tableview in SwiftUI but Text("Hi") is not allowing us to use Attributed text inside it.

So trying following code to display multiline HTML formatted text inside List. But with no success.

And cell height should be dynamic according to the content size height.

```
struct ContentView: View {
     @State var text = "Hello World This is line with more than two line of code to display as multiline textview inside the List cell."
    @State var bool: Bool = false
       var body: some View {
        List(0 ..< 5) { item in
                    TextView(text: self.$text)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
       }
}

struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let myTextView = UITextView()
        myTextView.delegate = context.coordinator

        myTextView.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 15)
        myTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
        myTextView.isEditable = false
        myTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        myTextView.backgroundColor = .clear  //UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.05)
        myTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
        return myTextView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }

    class Coordinator : NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent: TextView

        init(_ uiTextView: TextView) {
            self.parent = uiTextView
        }
        // with delegate methods implemented normally
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about if you do this:

```
myTextView.isScrollEnabled = true
```

does this work?

Comment: it shouldn't, as we need to increase the height of textview inside cell,  in UIKit we disable the scrolling for UITextView inside the tableviewcell in order to achieve content size height. And it didn't.

Comment: Your case yes it works, but we don't need to make it scrollable. Our requirement is to achieve dynamic height which should be the height of text content inside the List cell (tableview cell with dynamic height).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope it will help you.

(for any correction you want please put comment)

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let text = "<p>This is<br>a paragraph<br>with line breaks. This is <sup>superscripted</sup> text.</p>"
    @State var bool: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<5) { item in
            Text(self.text.htmlToAttributedString.string)
                .font(Font.system(size: 17))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        }
    }
}
```

**Extension**

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: please check this string "<font color=\"#bf360c\">Life is beautiful and everyone should love it and live it fully to their potential. Its not converting color and italics as in the tags here, <em>and</em> bright morning and cold nights.</font>".                   It works but not for all tags like in above string.

Comment: Got this link now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59731236/swiftui-attributed-string-from-html-crashes-the-app  but still its not showing more than two lines of text in Label.

Comment: I tried string which you mention in comment and it works for me. remove all tag also. 
tested in Xcode:11.2.1

Comment: it just displays it don't change the color as it should ( to <font color=\"#bf360c\">).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get for now the main link, from where I got this but it works as I needed.

```
ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                            ForEach(/*your implementation*/) { item in
                                UITextViewWrapper(text: self.$text, calculatedHeight: self.$size, onDone: nil)
                            }
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: proxy.size.width, minHeight: self.size, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    }
            }

fileprivate struct UITextViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = UITextView

    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var calculatedHeight: CGFloat
    var onDone: (() -> Void)?

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<UITextViewWrapper>) -> UITextView {
        let textField = UITextView()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator

        textField.isEditable = false
        textField.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        textField.isSelectable = false
        textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        textField.isScrollEnabled = true
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        if nil != onDone {
            textField.returnKeyType = .done
        }

//        textField.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<UITextViewWrapper>) {
        if uiView.text != self.text {
            uiView.text = self.text
        }
        if uiView.window != nil, !uiView.isFirstResponder {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        UITextViewWrapper.recalculateHeight(view: uiView, result: $calculatedHeight)
    }

    fileprivate static func recalculateHeight(view: UIView, result: Binding<CGFloat>)
    {
        let newSize = view.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        if result.wrappedValue != newSize.height
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                result.wrappedValue = newSize.height // !! must be called asynchronously
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text, height: $calculatedHeight, onDone: onDone)
//        return Coordinator()
    }

   final class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var text: Binding<String>
        var calculatedHeight: Binding<CGFloat>
        var onDone: (() -> Void)?

        init(text: Binding<String>, height: Binding<CGFloat>, onDone: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
            self.text = text
            self.calculatedHeight = height
            self.onDone = onDone
        }

        func textViewDidChange(_ uiView: UITextView) {
            text.wrappedValue = uiView.text
            UITextViewWrapper.recalculateHeight(view: uiView, result: calculatedHeight)
        }

        func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
            if let onDone = self.onDone, text == "\n" {
                textView.resignFirstResponder()
                onDone()
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS 15 you can use [AttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring) or `Markdown` with `Text`. And so you get multiline formatted text and dynamic cell height.

An example of using markdown:

```
Text("This text is **bold**, this is *italic*. This is a tappable link: [tap here](https://stackoverflow.com)")
```

`AttributedString` gives you more control over formatting. For example, you can change a link color or underline color:

```
var string = AttributedString("")

// you can use markdown with AttributedString    
let markdownText = try! AttributedString(markdown: "This is **bold** text. This is *italic* text.")

var tappableText = AttributedString(" I am tappable! ")
tappableText.link = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")
tappableText.foregroundColor = .green
    
var underlinedText = AttributedString("This is underlined text.")
underlinedText.underlineStyle = Text.LineStyle(pattern: .solid, color: .red)
    
string.append(markdownText)
string.append(tappableText)
string.append(underlinedText)

Text(string)
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: tappable text]